# AngularJS: how to call a function on page load

Tags: angularjs

```
var init = function(){
    $scope.getAllFriends($rootScope.rootName)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, function(err) {
            //error
        }); 
}
init();
$scope.getAllFriends = function(name){
    return friendService.getAllfriends(name)
}
```

Am new to angularjs, am trying to call a function on page load but am getting below error. Can anyone correct me where am wrong.

**TypeError: $scope.getAllFriends is not a function**

Comment: you can use ng-init="init()"  angular directive in html tag [see](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: show your html code for further assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a function not yet declared: getAllFriends has not been declared at the time init it's executed.

Hence, you are getting "TypeError: $scope.getAllFriends is not a function".

try like this instead:

```
var init = function () {
        $scope.getAllFriends()
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, function (err) {
                //error
            });
    }

$scope.getAllFriends = function (name) {
        return friendService.getAllfriends(name)
}
init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use named function instead of object. Like this:

```
function getAllFriends(name){...}
```